Obteniendo NUL en visual studio code al abrir cualquier archivo
Uso visual studio code con el plug-in ftp_simple para conectarme a un servidor remoto y desde visual studio code poder modificar mis archivos. Pero al abrir algún archivo obtengo un nul en los la parte de edición, comparto imagen para que puedan verlo.
Me he contactado con el proveedor de mi hosting pero no ha podido darme una solución, me dijero que era por la codificación que ocupa el archivo y el servidor pero ambos usan utf-8

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.
